# Create a 'like' feature for feeds using parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to create a 'like' feature for my android app using parse as backend.I am currently giving the user the option to like or dislike a post in the details screen. But I want to give the user the option to like a post in the feeds section instead of opening the details screen like tumblr,facebook,twitter and many other apps.I know one way of doing it is running a inner query for every post to check if the post is liked or not.But suppose I am loading 25 posts for the feeds section then I will need to run inner queries for the 25 posts at the same time which will cause performance overhead.So is there any other optimized way for doing.How is the anypic and other parse apps doing this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your `Post` class called `LikedBy` which is an array of pointers to users.

Whenever a user likes the post, add them to the array. Then when you query for the posts, use `includeKey` on the array and you will know who and how many people have liked it :)

Comment: Thank you for your response.But according to this discussion on  parse google community  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/d5cDc5nazNs  parse arrays only store fewer than 100 objects.So if the like amount increases more than 100 than this technique is dead .So is there any other way.Thank you.

Comment: Parse arrays can store any number of objects such that the total size is less than 128KB. The array size limit of 100 is a recommendation that Parse gave so that people did not have massive query results using `includeKey`. Depending on how many users you expect to like a post, arrays may or may not be viable. You should be perfectly fine if you expect the average case to have less than 1000 likes per post

Comment: If you are expecting an average greater than 1000 likes per post, then you will be better off modeling the likes using a relationship. The downside to this approach is that you will have to perform two queries to get the data you want. This is a design decision with tradeoffs that will vary from one app to another and what you expect the typical use case to be

Comment: Thank You.So if suppose the number of likes is more than 5000 per post then I should develop a like class.In the anypic tutorial they did created a like class for storing user likes .So can u explain to me how the anypic app got around with this approach.I am a android newbie and have no idea of Objective-C.So I did not understand the source code for anypic available in github.Can u please give it a look and provide some explanation to their approach.Thank You.

Comment: Not a problem at all! The AnyPic example uses a relationship to model any activity on a photo such as a like or comment. After looking at the code, there is one query to fetch all of photos to display and then each separate photo has a secondary query to load all of the activity related to it. This is a good approach if you want to display many different types of activity related to a given post, but at the cost of more queries. Don't forget to upvote and/or mark as answer if this is helpful :)

Comment: Thank you.So the anypic model to this situation is similar to my earlier thought of model using inner queries,right??? How about **caching in a offline database, all the 'likes' parse objects of a user in a cache and then checking for each post if the user has liked the post or not using a offline query**.Is this a good approach?Will it occupy more space?Will it cause a performance hit?What do you think of this approach? Please share your thoughts on this approach.Thank You.

Comment: Not exactly. An inner query typically means performing a *compound query* which is not what is happening in this case. AnyPic does use a compound query for joining all of the photos by friends and other sources, but all of the related activity (likes/comments) is queried separately. Caching offline is good for the user experience but you will still want to query database to check for updates. Performance of the query will be the same but the user will be able to use the app immediately with the cached data. It will use slightly more space to cache the objects but it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: So if a user a photo ,a like activity is created and is tried to be saved to the database .If successful ,then that like activity is added to the cache .When the user removes the like from the photo ,then the parse 'like' object is deleted and upon successful delete ,the cache is updated and that object is removed from cache.So will this model work ?Can I remove a single parse object from the parse offline cache?Please reply.Thank you.

Comment: Whose cache are you referring to? Each user will have their own offline cache which will need to be synchronized with Parse core for consistency. ***Any*** action that occurs needs to be reflected in Parse database which can then be synchronized with each user's offline cache

Comment: I am referring to each user cache.Upon login,I cache all the 'likes' objects that he has liked by using a simple query in the 'likes' class.Now whenever he likes a posts,a 'like' object is created and cached ,if successfully saved to the server.Whenever he removes a like from a post that particular 'like' object is removed from the server and (upon successful delete response) is also removed from the cache.Will this model work?Can I remove a single parse object from a parse offline cache?What do u think?Please reply and let me know if u have a better idea.

Comment: Yup that model would work. You should also look into using the Parse-provided local datastore. You can query against it, add, remove, and modify objects as you want and keep consistency by synchronizing the local datastore with parse core. See: http://blog.parse.com/learn/parse-local-datastore-for-ios/

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thank you anyways.